# PHP - How to block User after register - so manual approvement?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I have this Register Script, but they can instantly Login. I want to approve it by Hand first and then they should Login. I was looking in Google but cant find nothing about it. Thanks!

I fix it by changing to:

```html
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND active='1'");
```

```
<?php
    $showFormular = true; //Variable ob das Registrierungsformular anezeigt werden soll

    if(isset($_GET['register'])) {
        $error = false;
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
        $passwort1 = $_POST['passwort1'];
        $hotelname = $_POST['hotelname'];
        $ansprech = $_POST['ansprech'];
        $telefon = $_POST['telefon'];

        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo 'Please enter a valid Mail<br>';
            $error = true;
        }
        if(strlen($passwort) == 0) {
            echo 'Please enter a Passwort<br>';
            $error = true;
        }
        if($passwort != $passwort1) {
            echo 'The passwords must match<br>';
            $error = true;
        }

        //Überprüfe, dass die E-Mail-Adresse noch nicht registriert wurde
        if(!$error) {
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
            $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
            $user = $statement->fetch();

            if($user !== false) {
                echo 'This email address is already taken<br>';
                $error = true;
            }
        }

        //Keine Fehler, wir können den Nutzer registrieren
        if(!$error) {
            $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort, hotelname, ansprech, telefon) VALUES (:email, :passwort, :hotelname, :ansprech, :telefon)");
            $result = $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':passwort' => $passwort_hash, ':hotelname' => $hotelname, ':ansprech' => $ansprech, ':telefon' => $telefon));

            if($result) {
                echo '<center><b><h2>You have been registered successfully.<a href="login.php">To the login</a></b></center></h2></center>';
                $showFormular = false;
            } else {
                echo 'Unfortunately, an error occurred while saving<br>';
            }
        }
    }

    if($showFormular) {
        ?>
```

I dont want only with Email Confirm, or if its possible the best would be if after each User create a account, then I get the Mail to confirm they accounts.
Thanks!

Comment: Add column, call it approved When the user registers, set approved to 0. Then on your admin page, have a table which fetches the users with approved of 0. Then update the approved status to one. So on login, only users with approved of one can be granted access

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your issue you can add a "user_active" boolean column to your `users` table and set it to 0 when a user registers :

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort, hotelname, ansprech, telefon, user_active) VALUES (:email, :passwort, :hotelname, :ansprech, :telefon, 0)");
$result = $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':passwort' => $passwort_hash, ':hotelname' => $hotelname, ':ansprech' => $ansprech, ':telefon' => $telefon));
```

From there a user should be allowed to connect only if it's `user_active` value has been set to 1 (manually by an admin or by email confirmation if you want so).

Comment: Thanks! So I Need to Change my Login.php to check for user_active?

Comment: Yes this is exactly it

Comment: Uh thats sounds bit more complicated then I was thinking hehe.. or would it just be 1 Code line? Maybe you can Show me what a bit please :) ..

Comment: It should be quite straight forward. I guess that in your login.php page you have a condition to check if email and password matches your database, you should just add a condition to check if `user_active` is set to 1. If the condition is not satisfied you can display a message "account not confirmed"

Comment: Yes your are right so:
`if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['passwort'])) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];`